# How can I share working repository with another user (push/pull)?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-init

I've cloned a Git repository from Assembla by running:

```
git clone git@git.assembla.com:[my_project].git
```

How can I share my working repository (located at `/usr/local/project`) with another user, so that they can directly fetch/pull from and push to my working repository?

I already try to initialize the Git repository from my working repository by running:

```
git init
```

or

```
git init --bare
```

Then I used the other computer to push a commit to my working repository, but I receive the error:

```
Pushing to /usr/local/project/
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master[K
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository[K
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent[K
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match[K
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.[K
remote: error: [K
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to[K
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into[K
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you[K
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some[K
remote: error: other way.[K
remote: error: [K
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set[K
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.[K
To /usr/local/project/
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '/usr/local/project'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup a remote repo if you're going to be collaborating or even sharing amongst multiple computers. Generally people use a service such as Github or Unfuddle to host remote repos. However, you can also setup your own. The official Git [documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) will help you out.